# Simple addition in FSCL does not update result array

Tags: f#, opencl

```
open FSCL
open FSCL.Compiler
open FSCL.Language
open FSCL.Runtime

[<ReflectedDefinition; Kernel>]
let SimpleAdd(a: float32[], b: float32[], c: float32[], wi: WorkItemInfo) =
    let i = wi.GlobalID(0)

    c.[i] <- a.[i] + b.[i]


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let a = [| 1.0f; 2.0f |]
    let b = [| 2.0f; 3.0f |]
    let c = Array.zeroCreate 2
    let workItem = WorkSize(a.LongLength)
    <@ SimpleAdd(a, b, c, workItem) @>.Run() |> ignore
    printfn "%A" c
    0
```

This outputs [| 0.0f; 0.0f |]

I'm using F# compiler, which comes with VS2015. Console app targets F# 4.0 on .NET 4.5.1

**Update**

Strangely, this works as exptected:

```
[<ReflectedDefinition; Kernel>]
let SimpleAdd(a: float32[], b: float32[], wi: WorkItemInfo) =
    let i = wi.GlobalID(0)
    let c = Array.zeroCreate a.Length

    c.[i] <- a.[i] + b.[i]

    c
```

Comment: That is, because the last expression in a F# function is the return value of the function.

Comment: Hi Functional_S, if you're talking about why 2nd sample works - that I know. Question is: why 1st does not?

Answer (score 1):

The **second example DOES work**, because the last expression in a F# function is the return value of the function.

The **first example does NOT work**
because the F# quotation adds an other level of abstraction.

Its quotation looks like this

```
val x : Quotations.Expr<unit> =
  Call (None, SimpleAdd,
      [PropertyGet (None, a, []), 
       PropertyGet (None, b, []),
       PropertyGet (None, c, []), Value (1)])
```

And this does not allow (or depends on the evaluation implementation of the quotation) the side effect of the mutation of the Array (.NET reference type) back over the interface.

You can check the compiler implementation here https://github.com/FSCL/FSCL.Compiler
or maybe contact the author gabry.cocco@gmail.com of the FSCL.